# Proof for showing that a set of space curves form a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I basically have a smooth space curve $\alpha$,with curvature $\kappa$ and $\tau$, both non-zero, and I generate a family of curves $M_{\alpha} = \{\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu} : \mu \in (0, \infty) \}$ . The new curvature and torsion functions are now $\mu\kappa$ and $\mu\tau$. I wish to show that $M_{\alpha}$ is a smooth manifold.

I can get a multiplicative group structure on $M_{\alpha}$ through the multiplicative group structure on $(0, \infty)$. But will properties like local compactness of $(0, \infty)$ transfer onto $M_{\alpha}$. What kind of topological and geometric structure can $M_{\alpha}$ have??

Edit :> The curve $\alpha$ initially satisfies a functional relation of the form $f(\kappa, \mu) = \lambda$, $\lambda$ being a positive constant. The family $M_{\alpha} $ then arises out of curvature and torsion functions being modified as $\kappa_{\mu} = \mu\kappa$ and $\tau_{\mu} = \mu\tau$. Then $f(\kappa_{\mu}, \tau_{\mu}) = \lambda .\mu$, so I just defined a mapping $\psi :M_{\alpha} \to (0, \infty)$ as $$\psi(\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu}) = \mu$$ and ergo, $$\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu_1} * \dfrac{\alpha}{\mu_2} = \dfrac{\alpha}{\mu_1 . \mu_2}$$ is the multiplicative binary operation. Does what I have done seem sensible?

Comment: I don't understand your multiplicative group structure.  How are you defining the product of two points on $M_\alpha$?

Comment: @Jesse Madnick. I have edited the question to fill the gaps which you pointed out. I hope it fits in logically. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: I'm confused: you say that $\psi$ maps $(0,\infty) \to M_\alpha$, but do you mean $M_\alpha \to (0,\infty)$?  And I still don't understand how to multiply the point $\alpha(t)/\mu_1$ by $\alpha(s)/\mu_2$, where $t,s$ are different.

Comment: @Jesse Madnick. I am sorry about the first mistake, you are right. As for the parameters being different, well this might seem a little shady, but I have assumed that the all curves in $M_{\alpha}$ have been defined on the same domain of definition as $\alpha$, so $s$ is the parameter for all curves in $M_{\alpha}$, though $s$ is not the arc length parameter for any other curve apart from $\alpha$. I hope that does not make this problem go kaput. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: As for the edit, I don't know what you mean by "the curve $\alpha$ initially satisfies a functional relationship of the form $f(\kappa, \mu) = \lambda$."  Did you mean $f(\kappa, \tau) = \lambda$ instead?  Mistakes with such important information make it difficult to understand what you mean. You then say that the family $M_\alpha$ "arises out of curvature and torsion functions being modified by $\kappa_\mu = \mu \kappa$ and $\tau_\mu = \mu \tau$." So, what is $M_\alpha$ precisely? Does $M_\alpha$ consist of the curves $\alpha/\mu$, or do you now mean something else by $M_\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just make a few remarks.

First: Let $I$ be the domain of your smooth curve $\alpha \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$, which I'll assume to be an open interval.  The map
$$\begin{align}
X \colon I \times (0,\infty) & \to \mathbb{R}^3 \\
X(t,\mu) & = \mu \alpha(t)
\end{align}$$
is a smooth surjection onto $M_\alpha$.  The map $X$ will be an immersion at points $(t_0, \mu_0)$ for which the tangent vector $\alpha'(t_0)$ is **not** a scalar multiple of the position vector $\alpha(t_0)$.

That is, if the tangent vector $\alpha'(t_0)$ does not lie on the (radial) ray from the origin to the point $\alpha(t_0)$, then the map $X$ will be an immersion at $(t_0, \mu_0)$.

Second: Note that if the curve $\alpha$ ever intersects a ray emanating from the origin in two or more points, then the map $X$ will not be injective.  In particular, if $\alpha$ intersects itself, then $X$ will not be injective.

> **Conclusion:** If $\alpha$ is not tangent to any ray through the origin, and if $\alpha$ never intersects a ray through the origin in more than one point, then $M_\alpha$ is the image of an injective immersion.

Thus, in this case, $M_\alpha$ has a unique topology and smooth manifold structure for which $X \colon I \times (0,\infty) \to M_\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism.  In short: $M_\alpha$ is diffeomorphic to a plane in this case.

---

Here are two examples to illustrate the extent to which the above can fail if hypotheses are ignored.

(1) If $\alpha(t) = (t,0,0)$ is a segment of the $x$-axis, then $M_\alpha$ is literally just that same exact segment.  In other words, $M_\alpha$ is only $1$-dimensional in this example.

(2) Here is a more interesting example.  Consider a smooth curve $\alpha$ which has the following behavior:

- $\alpha(t)$ lies on the positive $x$-axis for $t \in (-\infty, 0)$
- $\alpha(t)$ lies on the quarter-plane $\{(x,y,0) \colon x,y > 0\}$ for $t \in (0, 1)$
- $\alpha(t)$ lies on the positive $y$-axis for $t \in (1, 2)$
- $\alpha(t)$ lies on the quarter-plane $\{(0,y,z) \colon y,z > 0\}$ for $t \in (2, 3)$
- $\alpha(t)$ lies on the vertical line $\{\alpha(3) + s(0,0,1)\}$ for $t \in (3, +\infty)$.

Then $M_\alpha$ is the union of the quadrant $\{(x,y,0) \colon x,y > 0\}$ in the $xy$-plane and the quadrant $\{(0,y,z) \colon y,z > 0\}$ in the $yz$-plane.

Comment: @Vishesh: What do you mean by "all the curves"?  Prior to your edit, you mentioned only one curve, $\alpha$.  The curves $\frac{1}{\mu}\alpha$ have the same domain as the single curve $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes the single curve $\alpha$ with curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$ generates the family $M_{\alpha}$, but if $\alpha$ is defined on $I$, then so si every other curve $\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu}$, right??Thats how I defined multiplication. But I guess what you are saying is that  at any given point $\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu_1}$ and $\dfrac{\alpha}{\mu_2}$ correspond to different points on the individual curves, so the multiplication is not well defined, am I right?

Comment: @Vishesh: Yes, everything you just said is right.

Comment: I am sorry for making it all  sound convoluted. So a group multiplication cannot be defined for this the way I did?

Comment: @Vishesh: It's not that a group multiplication can't be defined this way, it's that you haven't actually defined _anything_ aside from $\alpha(t)/\mu_1$ times $\alpha(t)/\mu_2$ for the same $t$.  You have not defined what you mean by, say, $\alpha(0)/2$ times $\alpha(1)/3$.  Perhaps you are confused because you keep referring to $\alpha/\mu$ as a point, when $\alpha/\mu$ is actually a curve.  A point looks like $\alpha(t)/\mu$, where a particular value of $t$ is plugged in, like $\alpha(7)/16$.

Comment: Aah yes, thats true. Is there some way to circumvent this and still get a meaningful group structure. I was also thinking of inducing a quotient topology on $M_{\alpha}$ using $(0,\infty)$ through the same kind of map $\psi$ or rather the inverse of $\psi$

Comment: @Vishesh: Well, if the conditions in the "Conclusion" of my post are met, then $M_\alpha$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so you should be able to transfer the group structure of $(\mathbb{R}^2, +)$ to $M_\alpha$ via the map $X$.  If the conditions in the "Conclusion" are not met, then it may still be possible (as in Example 1, for instance), but I don't know in general.  This is my absolute last comment on this post.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am sorry I guess I was pushing the nitpicking a bit too far. Yeah will look into all that you said. Cheers!!